# S3 Bucket / Cloudfront Redirects

Tags: amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

My current situation is that im doing Website redirects via S3 Bucket and Cloudfront. For example MY vendor gives me a website for a area ie. order.website.com/?id=12345 and create a Redirect on my end and Cname it too Area12345.website.com. Because this is what is advertised and what the customer uses.

Now this redirect works and we just switched to a different system/vendor "sort of speak" that used /Ordering/Home at the end of the URL;  and some users have a older version of our werbsite bookmaked which includeds /Home/Ordering at the end of the url so now when they click on thier bookmark they will get order.website.com/?id=12345home/ordering and it errors out.

I hope this makes sense

I have tired to work with S3 redirect conditions and cant seems to get anything to work

Any suggestions or let me know if my exmaples arnt clear

I tried creating S3 Reidrect conditions ie.

```
    "Condition": {
        "KeyPrefixEquals": "?id=1234ordering/home"
    },
    "Redirect": {
        "HostName": "order.website.com",
        "HttpRedirectCode": "301",
        "Protocol": "https",
        "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "?id=1234"
```

Ie the situation is. With that code when someone hits MY URL Area1234.Website.com for exmaple, they are Redirected to Order.website.com/?id=Lkdj2 Or w.e unique key im using.

Due too how the website was created in the past people may have OLD URLS bookmarked for exmaple they will have area1234.website.com/home/ordering when they use that bookedmarked url they get directed too Order.website.com/?id=Lkdj2home/ordering which casues a error.

I'm trying to remedy that home/ordering passing

Answer (score 0):

The JSON format used in the question is for redirects on static content hosted in S3. See [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects) This [blog](https://www.chrisdpeters.com/blog/full-domain-redirects-s3-and-cloudfront/#to-specific-path-on-another-site-appending-source-path) is also good for redirects between domains if the change was broader than just a key prefix.

Looking at your question and JSON, they don't seem to align. Your question appears to state that you want to redirect "home/ordering" and the new version is "ordering/home"; however, your condition is based on the new version and not the old. So, if you are trying to capture and redirect "home/ordering", your condition statement should reference that.

If you are not hosting in S3, you might be able to make use of the Rest API. See this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTRedirect.html).

Using CloudFront, if the request errors out every time (timeout, so a 504 error) and the path is universal, you can make use of CloudFront's custom error response to direct 504 errors to your desired path.

Comment: Hey 

I'm not hosting the website in S3.ATM via the Code above.

Ie the situation is.


With that code when someone hits MY URL  Area1234.Website.com for exmaple, they are Redirected to Order.website.com/?id=Lkdj2 Or w.e unique key im using.     



Due too how the website was created in the past people may have OLD URLS bookmarked for exmaple they will have area1234.website.com/home/ordering when they use that bookedmarked url they get directed too Order.website.com/?id=Lkdj2home/ordering which casues a error. 



I'm trying to remedy that home/ordering passing

Comment: Im a bit confused confused. I believe you can only use S3 redirects with the JSON format you list if you enable static website hosting. If you aren't hosting in S3 look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTRedirect.html) for the S3 Rest API instructions. I will also update my answer with a broader set of information depending on which direction you need to go.

Comment: Hey @rufus

Thanks for all your help - Just to level set.  If someone had my old ordering website booked the Link would like like Test1.website.com/home/ordering/  So when they click that link with my new Website because its  Ordering.website.com/id=1234 the /Home/ordering gets placed behid that unique ID Ordering.website.com/id=1234home/ordering causes a error pag.



And yes its not hosted in S3 ill check out Rest API